# It seems click button doesnt respond and increment the number each click

Tags: html, css, click, addeventlistener

Here is my code, I can't figure out what am I missing when clicking on the INCREMENT button nothing happens:

```js
let increment = document.getElementById("increment")
increment.addEventListener("click", plus());
let count = 0

function plus() {
  let count = 0
  document.getElementById("displayScreen").innerText = count++
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div id="displayScreen">-</div>
  <div id="container-btn">
    <button id="reset">reset</button>
    <button id="increment">increment</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed few problmes:

1. You initiallize `count` to be `0` every time `plus` is called.
2. `count++` means first assign, that increment. This way, the first time you click on increment, the value will be still `0`, and not `1` as you want.
3. `addEventListener` should get a callback on the 2nd parameter (a function that should be invoked when *clicking* the button. What *you* did is invoking `plus` in the 2nd paramer, returning `undefined` (since there's no `return` statement in `plus`), to `addEventListener`.

I added to working code:

```js
let increment = document.getElementById("increment");
increment.addEventListener("click", plus);
let count = 0;

function plus() {
  document.getElementById("displayScreen").innerText = ++count;
}
```

```html
<div id="displayScreen">-</div>
<div id="container-btn">
  <button id="reset">reset</button>
  <button id="increment">increment</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually from all you had written what literally fixed the problem was that i removed 
the ( ) from the plus function,
cause i thought you need to call a prepared function always with (  ),  thanks man

Comment: @tsurihe if you only remove the `()`, it will still show you `0` always.

Comment: Yeah yeah of course if fixed the rest of the code as well and saw it worked, what i meant is that was my main issue the ( ) cause in the beginning i didn't do the mistakes you have mentioned in the two sections